# mailchimp integration with django

Tags: python, django

i am trying to integrate mailchimp to my django site so that when users register they will receive a customized email that is already set on mailchimp. i don't know what to do please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Searching your exact title gives a ton of results and will easily solve your problem.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 i found something that met my needs exactly. thank you.